# Exponential heteroskedasticity

Tags: regression, least-squares, heteroscedasticity, consistency

Assume that the form of heteroskedasticity is exponential such that $u_{i} = e^{0.5X_{i}\gamma}\upsilon_{i}$ where it is assumed that $\upsilon_{i} \mid X_{i} \sim N\left(0,1\right)$ and $X_{i}$ includes an intercept. It can be shown that $\mathrm{Var}\left[u_{i} \mid X_{i}\right] = \mathrm{E}\left[u_{i}^2 \mid X_{i}\right] = e^{X_{i}\gamma}$. The aim is to estimate $\gamma$. Start by estimating $u_i$ with OLS residual $\hat{u}_i$. Consider $\hat{u}_i^2$ and take the logarithm of it, and then take the conditional expectation to obtain $\mathrm{E}\left[\ln\left(\hat{u}^{2}_{i}\right) \mid X_{i}\right] = X_{i}\gamma + \mathrm{E}\left[\ln\left(\upsilon_{i}^{2}\right)\right]$. $\mathrm{E}\left[\ln\left(\upsilon_{i}^{2}\right)\right]$ is some constant and it does not depend on $X_{i}$. The standard OLS regression will give consistent estimates for $\gamma$. However, the OLS estimator of the constant term will not be consistent. This is all what is told in a book. Why the OLS estimator of the constant is not consistent here? Is it because $X_i$ includes a constant and that $e^{\gamma_0}$ accounts for the constant?

Comment: What do you mean by the "OLS residual $\hat u_i$"?

Comment: In the linear regression we have $\hat{y}_i = {\textbf{x}}_{i}' \hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}$ and $\hat{u}_i = y_{i} - \hat{y}_i$.